System.ArgumentException: The path is empty. (Parameter 'path') while Executing file 'NSwag.json' with variables 'Configuration=Release
I am upgrading the API project "UserAuthContextService.AppServices" from
.NET6
Nswag.msbuild v13.18.0
To
.NET 8.
NSwag.msbuild v14.0.7
According to the post NSwag v14 announcement
and https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/4659#issuecomment-1880605207
The NSwag.json file is updated to below:
   {
   "runtime": "Net80",
   "defaultVariables": "Configuration=Release,OutDir=bin/Release/net8.0/,HomeDir=%USERPROFILE%",
   "documentGenerator": {
    "aspNetCoreToOpenApi": {
      "project": "UserAuthContextService.AppServices.csproj",
      "documentName": "v1",
      "msBuildProjectExtensionsPath": null,
      "configuration": null,
      "runtime": null,
      "targetFramework": null,
      "noBuild": true,
      "msBuildOutputPath": null,
      "verbose": true,
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "aspNetCoreEnvironment": null,
      "output": null,
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
    }
   },
    "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToCSharpClient": {
      "clientBaseClass": "",
      "configurationClass": "",
      "generateClientClasses": true,
      "suppressClientClassesOutput": false,
      "generateClientInterfaces": true,
      "suppressClientInterfacesOutput": false,
      "clientBaseInterface": null,
      "injectHttpClient": true,
      "disposeHttpClient": true,
      "protectedMethods": [],
      "generateExceptionClasses": true,
      "exceptionClass": "SwaggerException",
      "wrapDtoExceptions": true,
      "useHttpClientCreationMethod": true,
      "httpClientType": "System.Net.Http.HttpClient",
      "useHttpRequestMessageCreationMethod": false,
      "useBaseUrl": false,
      "generateBaseUrlProperty": true,
      "generateSyncMethods": true,
      "generatePrepareRequestAndProcessResponseAsAsyncMethods": false,
      "exposeJsonSerializerSettings": false,
      "clientClassAccessModifier": "public",
      "typeAccessModifier": "public",
      "propertySetterAccessModifier": "",
      "generateNativeRecords": false,
      "generateContractsOutput": false,
      "contractsNamespace": null,
      "contractsOutputFilePath": null,
      "parameterDateTimeFormat": "s",
      "parameterDateFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd",
      "generateUpdateJsonSerializerSettingsMethod": true,
      "useRequestAndResponseSerializationSettings": false,
      "serializeTypeInformation": false,
      "queryNullValue": "",
      "className": "{controller}Client",
      "operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromOperationId",
      "additionalNamespaceUsages": [],
      "additionalContractNamespaceUsages": [],
      "generateOptionalParameters": false,
      "generateJsonMethods": true,
      "enforceFlagEnums": false,
      "parameterArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable",
      "parameterDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "responseArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.List",
      "responseDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
      "wrapResponses": false,
      "wrapResponseMethods": [],
      "generateResponseClasses": true,
      "responseClass": "SwaggerResponse",
      "namespace": "Ag.Biisa.UserAuthContextService.Clients",
      "requiredPropertiesMustBeDefined": true,
      "dateType": "System.DateTime",
      "jsonConverters": null,
      "anyType": "object",
      "dateTimeType": "System.DateTime",
      "timeType": "System.TimeSpan",
      "timeSpanType": "System.TimeSpan",
      "arrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.List",
      "arrayInstanceType": null,
      "dictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
      "dictionaryInstanceType": null,
      "arrayBaseType": "System.Collections.Generic.List",
      "dictionaryBaseType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
      "classStyle": "Inpc",
      "jsonLibrary": "NewtonsoftJson",
      "generateDefaultValues": true,
      "generateDataAnnotations": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "excludedParameterNames": [],
      "handleReferences": false,
      "generateImmutableArrayProperties": false,
      "generateImmutableDictionaryProperties": false,
      "jsonSerializerSettingsTransformationMethod": null,
      "inlineNamedArrays": false,
      "inlineNamedDictionaries": false,
      "inlineNamedTuples": true,
      "inlineNamedAny": false,
      "generateDtoTypes": true,
      "generateOptionalPropertiesAsNullable": false,
      "generateNullableReferenceTypes": false,
      "templateDirectory": null,
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceSchemes": null,
      "output": "../UserAuthContextService.Clients/GeneratedClients.cs",
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
     }
     }
    }


In the project root directory, "Directory.Build.targets" file has the below command
<Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_NET80) run NSwag.json /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration),OutDir=$(OutDir),HomeDir=&quot;$(HomeDir)&quot; " />

While executing, the command throuws the error:
    Executing file 'NSwag.json' with variables   'Configuration=Release,OutDir=bin\Release\net8.0\,HomeDir=C:\Users\TT11'...
10>System.ArgumentException: The path is empty. (Parameter 'path')
10>   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)

But when I download the swagger.json file to the project directory and reconfigure the NSwag.json file as below, the API client code is generated in "GeneratedClients.cs".
   {
    "runtime": "Net80",
    "defaultVariables": "Configuration=Release,OutDir=bin/Release/net8.0/,HomeDir=%USERPROFILE%",
    "documentGenerator": {
      "fromDocument": {
        "json": "",
        "url": "swagger.json",
        "output": null,
        "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
      }
    },
    "codeGenerators": {
      "openApiToCSharpClient": {
      .........

Am I missing anything here?
I did google and read through the article text but no luck yet.

You are facing this issue might be because NSwag not being able to find or access certain paths or parameters correctly during the execution process. try to check all paths in your NSwag.json. Verify that variables like $(Configuration) in the Exec command are correctly resolved. Using the fromDocument section with a local swagger.json works, indicating potential issues with project-based OpenAPI generation. Ensure NSwag v14.0.7 compatibility with your settings, review verbose logs for detailed error insights, and consider using the stable workaround with swagger.json.
